# Convert Array of Objects in to one comma separated Object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have below array

const arr =

```
0: Object { 1: 1, 6: 1, 11: 1, … }
1: Object { 2: "3", 7: "", 12: "", … }
2: Object { 3: "3", 8: "", 13: "", … }
3: Object { 4: "", 9: "", 19: "3", … }
4: Object { 5: "4", 10: "", 15: "", … }
```

I want it to convert it like as with non empty values

> {1:2, 6:1, 11:1, 2:3, 3:3, 19:3, 5:4}

I tried below solutions:

```
let result = JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/(\[)(.+)(\])/g, "{$2}");
```

but i got result as

```
{{"1":1,"6":1,"11":1,"16":1},{"2":"3","7":"","12":"","17":""},{"3":"3","8":"","13":"","18":""},{"4":"","9":"","14":"","19":"3"},{"5":"4","10":"","15":"","20":""}}
```

Please assist in getting required response.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is a collision (where two objects have the same key)?

Comment: What would you do if some of the inner objects share the same `key`? Which one would you like to keep on the output?

Comment: Keys wont be duplicated. They are unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you  need to loop over all the indexes, then loop over all the keys and see if they have a value.

```js
var arr = [
  { 1: 1, 6: 1, 11: 1},
  { 2: "3", 7: "", 12: ""},
  { 3: "3", 8: "", 13: ""},
  { 4: "", 9: "", 19: "3"},
  { 5: "4", 10: "", 15: ""}
]

var out = arr.reduce((result, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (value !== "") {
      result[key] = Number(value)
    }
  })
  return result
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(out))
```

Comment: Can i get this as "{1:1, 6:1, 11:1, 2:3 .... and so on}"  ...like i need to strigify Object but not with JSON.stringify @epascarello

Comment: So reg exp to remove the quotes? `JSON.stringify(out).replace(/"/g,'')`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a snippet to get you started. For duplicate keys, the later will be preserved, but if that's not desired behavior, you can add a simple if condition to preserve the first occurrence or handle it as desired.

```js
let arr = [
  {1: 1, 6: 1, 11: 1,},
  {2: "3", 7: "", 12: "",},
  {3: "3", 8: "", 13: "",},
  {4: "", 9: "", 19: "3",},
  {5: "4", 10: "", 15: "",},
];

let output = {};
arr.forEach(a => Object.entries(a)
    .filter(([, value]) => value)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => output[key] = value));

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate a new `object`. In the next solution if there exist a shared key between the inner objects, the latest `value` will be stored on the final `object`. For cast/coerce the strings as number, we use the [unary plus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) operator:

```js
const arr = [
  {1: 1, 6: 1, 11: 1},
  {2: "3", 7: "", 12: ""},
  {3: "3", 8: "", 13: ""},
  {4: "", 9: "", 19: "3"},
  {5: "4", 10: "", 15: ""}
];

let res = arr.reduce((acc, obj) =>
{
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) =>
    {
        if (v !== "") acc[k] = +v;
    });

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the order is not of concern, this will provide the solution you are looking for:

```js
const arr = [
  { 1: 1, 6: 1, 11: 1 },
  { 2: "3", 7: "", 12: "" },
  { 3: "3", 8: "", 13: "" },
  { 4: "", 9: "", 19: "3" },
  { 5: "4", 10: "", 15: ""}
];

let reduced = arr.reduce((acc, val) => {
  Object.assign(acc,
    Object.keys(val)
    .filter(key => val[key])
    .reduce((res, key) => (res[key] = +val[key], res), {})
  );
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(reduced));
```